# Return array from method and add to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write a class that will filter an array and return the results. Basically I have a large multidimensioanl array `$companyArray` that contains an array for each company which contains "Company Name, Address, City, State, Phone etc." I need to sort through the sub array for each company and see if any fields are blank, if a field is blank return an array that contains all the fields for that company that are blank and add them to another array where I called the method so that I know which companies contain blank values. This will be extended to check other fields for things such as "Commas, New Lines, etc."

Here is my code so far:

This is a method inside of my `Test` class where I pass all the values into the `Filter` class and where I would like the returned fields to be placed inside of the `$badArray`

```
public function CleanData($companyArray) {

        $filtered = new Filter;
        $badArray = array();
        foreach($companyArray as $row => $value) {

            if($filtered->Blank($value)) {
                $badArray[$value['Company_Name']] = $filtered->Blank();
            } else {

            }



        }
        echo "<PRE>";
        print_r($badArray);
        echo "</PRE>";
            //$this->SortGoodFromBad($badArray, $companyArray);

    }
```

This is a method inside of my `Filter` class:

```
public function Blank($value) {
    $blank = array();
    foreach($value as $row => $content) {
        if(trim($value[$row] == "")){
            $blank[$value['Company_Name']][] = " Contains Blank " . $row;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return $blank;
}
```

This is an example of the `$companyArray`

```
array(

    [0] = array(

            'Company_Name' = "My Company"
            'Address' = "2101 Big Walk way"
            'Phone' = "555-555-5555"
            'Website' = ""
            )

    [1] = array(

        'Company_Name' = "My Other Company"
        'Address' = ""
        'Phone' = ""
        'Website' = "http://mylittlecompany.com"
        )

    [2] = array(

        'Company_Name' = "My Super Company"
        'Address' = "2101 Other Walk Way"
        'Phone' = "555-555-5555"
        'Website' = "http://example.com"

    )

)
```

I want the `$badArray` in the end to look something like this

```
array(

    ["My Company"] = array(
        [0] = 'Contains blank Website'
        )

    ["My Other Company"] = array(
        [0] = 'Contains blank Address'
        [1] = 'Contains blank Phone'
        )
)
```

Notice that `My Super Company` did not appear in the above array because it contains a field in all places. Can someone help me figure this out? If I dump the `$blank` array I have it setup as intended for that specific company. I need to return this back and add it to the `$badArray`

Comment: I've posted a solution that seems to do what you want. If it doesn't fit the bill, please let me know and I'll amend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

```
function CleanData($companyArray) {
    $filtered = new Filter;
    $badArray = array();
    foreach($companyArray as $row => $value) {
        $aFilter = $filtered->Blank($value);
            if ($aFilter !== false) {
                $badArray[$value['Company_Name']] = $aFilter;
            }
    }
    echo "<PRE>";
    print_r($badArray);
    echo "</PRE>";
}
```

Blank (from Filter class)

```
class Filter
{
    public function Blank($value) {
        $blank = array();
        foreach($value as $row => $content) {
            if(trim($content) == "") {
                $blank[] = " Contains Blank " . $row;
            }
        }

        if (count($blank) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $blank;
    }
}
```

A couple issues with the original code :

```
else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

This immediately returns FALSE on the first item that is not blank. So unless a record was 100% blank, it would have never been added to the array.

```
if(trim($value[$row] == "")){
```

the trim function encapsulates too much (== ""). Additionally I've changed it to $content since it's available at this point. No reason to defreferance in to the array when it's already split for you.

If you have questions about any of my other changes, let me know.